# CPU throttled to base speed or 0.8 GHz even after disabling intelppm

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance, battery, power-management

I have a laptop with Intel i7-4750HQ processor @ 2.00 GHz base speed and turbo boost up to 3.00 GHz. My laptop battery died a few months ago and as I have a home inverter, I've been using it with AC power without the battery. But the clock speeds are either stuck at 0.89 GHz or 2.00 GHz. The following are the things I have tried.

**Power Plan:**

- *High Performance* since the beginning.
- Max and min processor state = *100%*.
- System cooling policy = *Active*.
- Energy Efficient Optimization = *Disabled*.

---

**Changing intelppm settings**

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\intelppm`.

1. *Action:* `Start` to `4` and restart (with and without battery)

   *Result:* CPU stuck at 2.00 GHz. <sup>Why is it happening? It should work at max clock speed right? Why turbo boost won't work in this case?</sup>
2. *Action:* `Start` to `1` and restart (with and without battery)

   *Result:* CPU sometimes works at 3.00 GHz all the time, but in a few hours, it comes back to 0.80 GHz and stays there permanently. Even stress tests won't bring it back to normal speed.
3. *Action:* `Start` to `3` and restart (with and without battery)

   *Result:* CPU sometimes works at 3.00 GHz all the time, but in a few hours it comes back to 1.50 to 2.00 GHz. And like 1, stress test won't 'boost' it too.

---

**Unplugging and plugging the power cord**

*Action:* Repeated the `intelppm` settings

*Result:* Same effect.

---

**Uninstalled Intel Collaborative Processor Performance Control (CPPC) Driver**

*Action:* Did this from device manager

*Result:* It installed itself upon restart and has no effect on any settings.

---

**Additional info:**

- My idle temperatures average around 47 °C to 50 °C. Full load goes upto 75 °C to 80 °C.
- Tried using stress test to see if the processor can reach high speed. When CPU is stuck in 0.8 GHz, or 2.x GHz, they never reach 3.0 Ghz.
- To eliminate any thermal throttling cases, I tried stress testing the CPU when it is at 3.0 GHz. There were no throttling. And in some cases it only got throttled down to 2.5 GHz only to come back to 3.0 GHz when the stress test was stopped.

**CPU Test**

```
--- IPDT64 - Revision: 4.1.4.36
--- IPDT64 - Start Time: 25-06-2020 16:37:04

----------------------------------------------
-- Testing
----------------------------------------------
CPU 1 - Genuine Intel - Pass.
CPU 1 - BrandString - Pass.
CPU 1 - Cache - Pass.
CPU 1 - MMXSSE - Pass.
CPU 1 - IMC - Pass.
CPU 1 - Prime Number - Pass.
CPU 1 - Floating Point - Pass.
CPU 1 - Math - Pass.
CPU 1 - GPUStressW - Pass.
CPU 1 - CPULoad - Pass.
CPU 1 - CPUFreq - Pass.

IPDT64 Passed
--- IPDT64 - Revision: 4.1.4.36
--- IPDT64 - End Time: 25-06-2020 16:40:57

----------------------------------------------
PASS
```

**Speccy report** - https://dpaste.org/2MNV/slim

---

What is causing this throttling? How do I disable the throttling and have my CPU run at max clock speed all the time? My BIOS doesn't have any processor energy management options.

---

**Update:** I believe mine is a faulty firmware at this point. Because, when I boot up the laptop, it remains at max speed for a while. Then when it goes to base speed, I turn on ThrottleStop and exit it. This brings back the processor to 3+ GHz and it stays there for the rest of the day without any issues. I'm gonna have to wait for firmware updates or put ThrottleStop in my startup.

Comment: CPU throttling can happen based on other temperature sensors in your system, use a comprehensive tool and have a look if there are other high temperatures.

Comment: ^ Such as Speccy

Comment: @Mokubai, I used speccy and everything shows normal. Not temp spikes. Processors are idling around ~55 °C. Here is the speccy report. https://dpaste.org/2MNV/slim

Comment: Have you tried to remove the driver?  I assume your power plan is properly configured?

Comment: Power plan is properly configured, yes. By driver you mean the intelppm driver? Does renaming it disable it?

Comment: I had the dead battery in my laptop. So tried all these tests with it. And then removed it and tried again without it. Now I am running the laptop on AC power only. The battery is not attached to the laptop at the moment.

Comment: I don't know if this is still true.. ***but it used to be***.  Throttling will not work properly in many laptops without a working battery installed.  I have run into this myself on an i7 when I couldn't get above 1.8 when 3 should have been the boosted speed.  [See for yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=laptop+turbo+boost+without+battery&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS868US868&oq=laptop+turbo+boost+without+battery)